# Google Analytics Page Views vs AWS requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-analytics, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

There's a strange anomaly happening in the stats on Google Analytics and on AWS. In the same minute, GA recorded 10 page views, but AWS recorded 7000 requests on ELB (Elastic Beanstalk load balancer). Another data point slightly later, GA 4 page views, AWS 1200 requests.

How in general can this be interpreted? Is every page view generating 300 - 700 requests on the ELB? This seems like an enormous amount of requests per page view.

Below are the images of ELB monitoring (per minute) and GA data in roughly the same period.

[image: AWS ELB data]

[image: Google Analytics]

Comment: We had a similar issue; turned out to be bots / crawlers.

Comment: @hephalump Did you eventually get rid of the bots and how did it change later?